# Vertical Tabs Bulma

Tags: css, bulma

Is there a simple css code for bulma making their horizontal tabs to vertical tabs? (sample below) I just want to overwrite their css

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="is-active"><a>Pictures</a></li>
    <li><a>Music</a></li>
    <li><a>Videos</a></li>
    <li><a>Documents</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some more code, like css or specify your question? If I think what you want, maybe this is your answer; <style>ul li { display: block; width: 100%; clear: both;}</style>

Comment: I was checking their documentation and you can use this approach 
http://bulma.io/documentation/grid/tiles/

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid there isn't a simple class to add in Bulma to achieve this (or at least not that I'm aware of). But since Bulma is using flexbox you can achieve a lot by simply overwriting the `flex-direction`.

```
.tabs ul {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgzz0zxd/19/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Very late to on this one but if it helps anyone else.  I use a horizontal tile with 2 children.  The first child I use a panel without a heading, just panel blocks that are anchor tags for my vertical tabs, the second child a div to put the target content of the anchor tag in.  Switches to tabs on top and content on bottom at mobile breakpoint.  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xysn17hw/2/)

```js
<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
      <div class="tile box is-parent is-horizontal">
        <div class="tile is-child is-2">
          <nav class="panel datanav">
            <a class="panel-block">Families</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Members</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Member Birthdays</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Member Cars</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Sponsors</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Newsletter Mailed</a>
            <a class="panel-block">Newsletter Electronic</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="tile is-child is-10 has-background-white-ter">
          CONTENT
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```